# How can i display all buttons to right in bootstrap panel heading?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display buttons to the right in bootstrap `panel-heading` i tried to add pull-right class on all buttons but its breaking some css rules on `panel-body`, How can i display all buttons on right side in bootstrap `panel-heading` ?

main.html

```
   <div class="col-md-11">
    <div ng-show="showMessage">
        <p class="recordMessage">File is being recorded to the server ,once you stop recording it will prompt for cancel or download. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">DIT LOGS
            <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right: 300px">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rad btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-rad btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-rad btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-rad btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body display-logs" scroll-bottom="event">
            <ul style="list-style: none;">
                <li ng-repeat="message in event track by $index" ng-class="{lastItem: $last}"><span><strong>Log:</strong></span><span>{{message}}</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it looks like it works in jsfiddle. Buttons are in the right of panel-heading

Comment: it loooks normal in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/palak6041/2addy81v/ Can you provide working example where it is having issue

Comment: i added more code to the question if you try now you will see the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try putting them in an other div

```
<div class="panel-heading">DIT LOGS
    <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rad btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-rad btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-rad btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-rad btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope! still running out of panel-body , i edited my question and added little more code to understand.

Comment: do you mean that they are bigger than the header or that they are not on the right side you have to remove the inline style that adds 300px padding

Comment: i removed padding , they are bigger than header thats why panel-body having issue

Comment: ok now exchange btn-lg with btn-xs on buttons and you are done :D

Comment: @RudiUrbanek small edit, that seems to be working fine. http://plnkr.co/edit/au3Z8ww8OK37QRUYzT9a?p=preview. `btn-rad` is not from bootstrap as I can imagine. And for clarity in answer you can wrap panel text in `div.pull-left` as well. It will brake viewing. But after adding `.clearfix` to `.panel-heading` then everything is okay.